# Complications between landscape and landscape

Tags: landscape, bigfoot

I have in my document two pages in landscape format. My problem: the line break is set to early (at the half
of the line).
I have checked my code and the problem seems to be "bigfoot": When I delete it, it works. However, I need the bigfoot-package
for other elements of my document and therefore I want to ask how I can solve this issue?

```
 \RequirePackage[patch]{kvoptions} 
\documentclass[open=any,12pt,oneside,headings=standardclasses,chapterprefix=false,pointlessnumbers]{scrbook} %headsepline
\let\Tiny=\tiny


\addtolength{\headsep}{-.5\baselineskip} %abstand kopfzeile text kleiner

\usepackage{scrbase}
\providecommand*{\Ifstr}{\ifstr}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline=.5pt]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\renewcommand*{\headfont}{\normalfont}
\ohead{\pagemark}
\ihead{\headmark}
\ofoot{}

\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}

\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  rightmargin,
  contents={%
    \parbox[\layerheight][c]{\dimexpr\footskip+\footheight\relax}{%
      \hfill\rotatebox{90}{\pagemark}}}
]{lscape.foot}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  textarea,
  addhoffset=\dimexpr-\headsep-\headheight\relax,
  width=\dimexpr\headsep+\headheight\relax,
  contents={\hfill\rotatebox{90}{\headmark}\hspace*{\headsep}}
]{lscape.head}
\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{lscape}{}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{bigfoot}

\begin{document}


\section{Introduction}

Hallo\footnote{sdfdsfsdfsdf sdfdsfsdfsdf sdfdsfsdfsdf sdfdsfsdfsdfsdfdsfsdfsdf sdfdsfsdfsdf sdfdsfsdfsdf sdfdsfsdfsdfsdfdsfsdfsdf sdfdsfsdfsdf}

\newpage
\begin{landscape}
\pagestyle{lscape}
  

sdfdsfsdfsdf\footnote{sdfdsfsdfsdf sdfdsfsdfsdf sdfdsfsdfsdf sdfdsfsdfsdfsdfdsfsdfsdf sdfdsfsdfsdf sdfdsfsdfsdf sdfdsfsdfsdfsdfdsfsdfsdf sdfdsfsdfsdf}


\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\makeatletter\AddToHook{env/landscape/begin}{\MFL@columnwidth\textheight}\makeatother`. This assumes a current LaTeX.

Comment: Thanks, it works!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
\makeatletter
\AddToHook{env/landscape/begin}{\MFL@columnwidth\textheight}
\makeatother.
```

This assumes a current LaTeX.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more what that code is doing?